# Cuando se ordena por columna en una tabla que esta se cambie de color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estoy intentando  que cuando se ordene la columna es decir cuando se haga click en el thead, la columna entera se cambie de color, para saber cual esta ordenada

y tengo la siguiente funcion de ordenación: he pensado que cuando entre en la línea de ordenar, que cambie toda la columna

La tabla es normal, con sus thead y tbody, el script de ordenacion no discrimina acentos  y tiene la clase sortable en el table tag

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let tables = document.querySelectorAll('.sortable');
  tables.forEach(table => {
      let tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
      let trs = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr');
      if(trs.length == 0) {
          // Nada que hacer con esta tabla
          return;
      }
      // Ascendente o descendente
      let order, lastColumn;
      // Asignar número para poder acceder y mover a ubicación final
      trs.forEach((tr, trNum) => tr.dataset.num = trNum);
      // Obtener celdas de título para asignar evento y ordenar al hacer clic
      let ths = table.querySelectorAll('thead th');
      ths.forEach((th, column) => th.addEventListener('click', () => {
          // Crear un arreglo con dato de fila y valor de celda
          let values = [];
          trs.forEach(tr => {
              values.push({
                  trData: tr.dataset.num,
                  value: tr.querySelectorAll('td')[column].innerText
              });
          });
          // Ordenar valores
          values.sort((a,b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value));
          // Definir el orden en que se va a mostrar
          if(lastColumn !== column) {
              // Si el clic no es en la misma columna que el anterior
              // Restablecer orden
              order = null;
          }
          lastColumn = column;
          // Definir el orden de salida
          if(!order || order == 'DESC') {
              // En el primer clic en la misma columna, order es nulo
              order = 'ASC'
          } else {
              order = 'DESC';
          }
          if(order == 'DESC') {
              values.reverse();
          }
          // Ordenar tabla
          values.forEach(data => {
              let trMove = table.querySelector(`[data-num="${data.trData}"]`);
              tbody.appendChild(trMove);
          });
      }));
  });
});

</script>
```

Como podría ponerlo para la forma que quiero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el `click` en un `th` se le añade una clase que le da en este caso color de fondo:

```
 th.classList.add('red');
...
 tr.querySelectorAll('td')[column].classList.add('red');
```

He añadido una clase "celda" a los `th` y `tr` para eliminar el `background` de otras columnas que se hayan podido clickar antes:

```
$(".celda").removeClass('red');
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let tables = document.querySelectorAll('.sortable');
  tables.forEach(table => {
      let tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
      let trs = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr');
      if(trs.length == 0) {
          // Nada que hacer con esta tabla
          return;
      }
      // Ascendente o descendente
      let order, lastColumn;
      // Asignar número para poder acceder y mover a ubicación final
      trs.forEach((tr, trNum) => tr.dataset.num = trNum);
      // Obtener celdas de título para asignar evento y ordenar al hacer clic
      let ths = table.querySelectorAll('thead th');
      ths.forEach((th, column) => th.addEventListener('click', () => {
          // Crear un arreglo con dato de fila y valor de celda          
          $(".celda").removeClass('red');
          th.classList.add('red');
          let values = [];
          trs.forEach(tr => {
              values.push({
                  trData: tr.dataset.num,
                  value: tr.querySelectorAll('td')[column].innerText
              });
              tr.querySelectorAll('td')[column].classList.add('red'); 
          });
          // Ordenar valores
          values.sort((a,b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value));
          // Definir el orden en que se va a mostrar
          if(lastColumn !== column) {
              // Si el clic no es en la misma columna que el anterior
              // Restablecer orden
              order = null;
          }
          lastColumn = column;
          // Definir el orden de salida
          if(!order || order == 'DESC') {
              // En el primer clic en la misma columna, order es nulo
              order = 'ASC'
          } else {
              order = 'DESC';
          }
          if(order == 'DESC') {
              values.reverse();
          }
          // Ordenar tabla
          values.forEach(data => {
              let trMove = table.querySelector(`[data-num="${data.trData}"]`);
              tbody.appendChild(trMove);
          });
      }));
  });
});
```

```css
.red { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="sortable">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="celda">Col1</th>
    <th class="celda">Col2</th>
    <th class="celda">Col3</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="celda">a</td>
    <td class="celda">b</td>
    <td class="celda">c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="celda">b</td>
    <td class="celda">c</td>
    <td class="celda">a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="celda">c</td>
    <td class="celda">a</td>
    <td class="celda">b</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias es lo que tenia pensado, pero no lograba acceder a la misma columna me faltaba esta linea de codigo,>tr.querySelectorAll('td')[column].classList.add('red');